# Custom view loaded from NIB is always rotated 90 degrees

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that only works in landscape, i.e. is configured with

```c
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

I have a custom `UIView` (*not* View Controller) with its own NIB. I load it in the view controller with

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ISMainView *customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ISMainView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    [self.view addSubview:customView];
}
```

When the view loads it's displayed rotated by 90 degrees, as if it wants to be in portrait orientation.

Any idea what's wrong? A `UIView` doesn't know anything about its own orientation, right? So the problem must be with the View Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears the problem was being caused by

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

I'm not sure why, but turning off `shouldAutorotate` prevented the subview from being set to the proper device orientation, even though the device never rotates. Odd.